# Selecting distinct objects from collection of objects using lambda expressions

Tags: linq, nhibernate, lambda, repository

We have a project using Fluent NHibernate. There is an object called BluePart with a property of Oem of type Oem.

```
public class BluePart : DomainEntity
{
    ...
    public virtual Oem Oem { get; set; }
}
```

The Oem object has several properties including OemCode and OemDescription.

```
public class Oem : DomainEntity
{
    ...
    public virtual string OemCode { get; set; }
    public virtual string OemDescription { get; set; }
}
```

I am trying to build a linq query using lambda expressions that will get all distinct Oems from a list of BlueParts (2.7million records). Ideally it should produce the following sql (which runs in <1sec):

```
select distinct o.OemCode, o.OemDescription 
From BluePart b inner join Oem o on o.OemId = b.Oem_id
```

Below is the query I built which returns all Oems, regardless of distinctness.

```
var oem = repository.Query<BluePart>().Select(x => new Oem { OemCode =
x.Oem.OemCode, OemDescription = x.Oem.OemDescription}).ToList();
```

I thought this query would be easy to build but it's not turning out to be that way. When running a GroupBy (.GroupBy(z => z.OemCode)), I keep getting an error saying the property I try to GroupBy is not a property of Bluepart (which it shouldn't be because I'm grouping on a property of Oem)

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
var oem = repository.Query<BluePart>()
                    .Select(x => new { OemCode = x.Oem.OemCode, 
                                       OemDescription = x.Oem.OemDescription})
                    .Distinct()
                    .ToList();
```

This will *only* get you the distinct code/description pairs, but it looks like that's all you're interested in.

Alternatively, using grouping:

```
var oem = repository.Query<BluePart>()
                    .GroupBy(x => new { OemCode = x.Oem.OemCode, 
                                        OemDescription = x.Oem.OemDescription})
                    .ToList();
```

This will get you all the `BluePart` entities grouped by OEM code/description.

Comment: The first option is still not returning a collection of distinct oems but rather a list of alike anonymous types.

The second, returns an error of

{"Unable to cast object of type 'System.Object[]' to type 'System.Linq.IGrouping`2[<>f__AnonymousType2`2[System.String,System.String],Core.Domain.Model.BluePart]'."}

Comment: @Brett: Yes, as I said the first will only get code/description pairs, although they should be distinct ones. That matches the SQL query you described. Where is the error coming up with the second option? I don't see where you'd end up with an `object[]`.

Comment: There has got to be something else going on here. The first query is not returning distincts. The sql it's producing does not have any distinct in it. However the second option is actually producing the correct sql, but also producing that casting error. I'll post the reason for the casting error when I find it.

Comment: @Brett: I suspect that's an NHibernate weakness then... I'm pretty sure both would work in LINQ to SQL or LINQ to EF :(