# Do I need to define all the elements in an XML Object?

Tags: c#, xml, windows-phone-7

```
var block = (from query in data.Descendants("block")
             where query.Element("itemid").Value == argID.ToString()
             select new Block
             {
                Name = (string)query.Element("name"),
                ItemID = (int)query.Element("itemid"),
                Description = (string)query.Element("description")
             }
             ).Single();
```

Do I need to define all the fields from my XML document? Or is there an easier way since I'm defining the Block already.

```
public class Block
    {
        int itemid;
        string name;
        string description;


        public string Name
        {
            get { return name; }
            set { name = value; }
        }

        public int ItemID
        {
            get { return itemid; }
            set { itemid = value; }
        }

        public string Description
        {
            get { return description; }
            set { description = value; }
        }

        public string Price
        {
            get { return price; }
            set { price= value; }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean do you have to pull everything from the xml file into your object, the answer is no.

You can populate which ever content you want from the xml into your model.

With regard to your object, whether you have to populate everything in your destination object the answer is no also, unless you have rules on your domain objects that must be satisfied, but that code's in your control.

Comment: But to use a field from my xml I do need to put that into the object correct?

Comment: You'd need to put it in "an" object. Since you're newing a Block, you could add it to Block if it makes sense for Block to carry this. Alternatively you could make an intermediary type to represent the domain data your pulling in, then split the data out to different objects. Or you could load it into an anonymous type. A sample of that here by Jon Skeet. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3344133/selecting-distinct-objects-from-collection-of-objects-using-lambda-expressions

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to explain this.